# Selenium no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I can locate the element via XPath in HTML page, but in selenium, it is showing unable to locate the element.

Below is my Xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='navbar-collapse collapse']//li[@ng-class='{active:contactActive}']//span[contains(text(),'Contact Manager')]")).click();
```

Also, I cannot share my HTML Page.

Comment: you need to explicitly wait for the element to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes explicitly wait is only partially Working. But after using Explicit wait its showing another error called "Unable to click on an element using Selenium". Then I had to use "JavascriptExecutor" detailed below to get this working.

WebElement Importbuilding=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-1 add_building margin_left25 col-xs-3 ng-scope']//button"))));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Importbuilding);

Answer (score 0):

You provided really few information regarding your problem, so i'll give general answer for general question:

precondition - you have locator
`//div[@class='navbar-collapse collapse']//li[@ng-class='{active:contactActive}']//span[contains(text(),'Contact Manager')]`

1. **Possible issue 1** let's assume that locator correct - so there's possible situation that driver checks element before it appears

> **Solution:**
>
> a. ensure in debug mode that element is visible on step when driver is
>   searching for it - item is not collapsed, not overlapped, visible,
>   exist.
>
> b. be sure that element is loaded when driver is actually searching
>   for it. Add explicit wait.

2. **Issue 2**
   `//div[@class='navbar-collapse collapse']` - such locator is always source of problems, because your div should have class exactly equal to `navbar-collapse collapse`, in the same order. Locator will fail if another class will be added, or classes will be orderer in another way.

> **Solution** - it's better to use 'contains' locators instead of 'equals' `//div[contains(@class,'navbar-collapse')]`

3. **Issue 3** - this locator tells you not really much about element you are searching for. It just says that elements should be located inside collapsible div. Same problem with li part of your locator.

> **Solution:**
>
> a. try to use more informative locators (classes/ids), as it will be
>   really easier to maintain (understand what locator is looking for and
>   update for correct one) when not abstract "collapse", but "userItem"(
>   for example) class used.
>
> b. reduce complexity - remove unneeded part of locators. Do you really
>   need that part of locator `//div[@class='navbar-collapse collapse']` ?
>   Will locator work logically/correctly if you remove this part? I
>   believe so). Is that important for 'Contract Manager' to be placed inside `span` and not `div`? If no - use `*` for tag indication. And so on.